# Update with ISNULL and operation

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.5

original query looks like this :

```
UPDATE reponse_question_finale t1, reponse_question_finale t2 SET 
t1.nb_question_repondu = (9-(ISNULL(t1.valeur_question_4)+ISNULL(t1.valeur_question_6)+ISNULL(t1.valeur_question_7)+ISNULL(t1.valeur_question_9))) WHERE t1.APPLICATION = t2.APPLICATION;
```

I know you cannot update 2 tables in a single query so i tried this :

```
UPDATE reponse_question_finale t1
  SET nb_question_repondu = (9-(COALESCE(t1.valeur_question_4,'')::int+COALESCE(t1.valeur_question_6,'')::int+COALESCE(t1.valeur_question_7)::int+COALESCE(t1.valeur_question_9,'')::int)) 
WHERE t1.APPLICATION = t1.APPLICATION;
```

But this query gaves me an error : `invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

I saw that the Postgres equivalent to MySQL is COALESCE() so i think i'm on the good way here.
I also know you cannot add varchar to varchar so i tried to cast it to integer to do that. I'm not sure if i casted it correctly with parenthesis at the good place and regarding to error maybe i cannot cast to int with coalesce.
Last thing, i can certainly do a co-related sub-select to update my two tables but i'm a little lost at this point.

The output must be an integer matching the number of questions answered to a backup survey.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you repeat the same table twice in the original update statement? That does make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value from the list supplied. So, if the column value is null the expression `COALESCE(t1.valeur_question_4,'')` returns an empty string and that's why you get the error.

But it seems you want something completely different: you want check if the column is `null` (or empty) and then subtract a value if it is to count the number of non-null columns.

To return `1` if a value is not null or `0` if it isn't you can use:

```
(nullif(valeur_question_4, '') is null)::int
```

`nullif` returns null if the first value equals the second. The `IS NULL` condition returns a `boolean`  (something that MySQL doesn't have) and that can be cast to an integer (where `false` will be cast to `0` and `true` to `1`)

So the whole expression should be:

```
nb_question_repondu = 9 - (
                              (nullif(t1.valeur_question_4,'') is null)::int
                            + (nullif(t1.valeur_question_6,'') is null)::int
                            + (nullif(t1.valeur_question_7,'') is null)::int
                            + (nullif(t1.valeur_question_9,'') is null)::int
                          )
```

Another option is to unpivot the columns and do a select on them in a sub-select:

```
update reponse_question_finale
  set nb_question_repondu = (select count(*) 
                              from (
                                values 
                                  (valeur_question_4), 
                                  (valeur_question_6), 
                                  (valeur_question_7), 
                                  (valeur_question_9)
                              ) as t(q) 
                              where nullif(trim(q),'') is not null);
```

Adding more columns to be considered is quite easy then, as you just need to add a single line to the `values()` clause

Comment: I chose the one with `nb_question_repondu = 9 - (
                              (nullif(t1.valeur_question_4,'') is null)::int` and now it works correctly. Thanks to take the time to help us (rookies) Horse.